# Multiple MariaDB databases in Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

Using Docker (v.2) I have a database set up in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
mysql:
    image: mariadb:latest
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'test'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'test'
      MYSQL_USER: 'test'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'test'
```

This works fine. What do I need to do to create another database in the same container?

Comment: Could you please explain more about another container? Is it another instanc of MariaDB? Or you want to host another DB like Moongo DB?

Comment: In MySQL speak, a single mysqld instance supports multiple databases - they share common resources such as the connection ports and authentication definition (but may have distinct permissions). Do you just want a single instance running multiple databases or do you want multiple instances?

Comment: It sounds like I want a single instance running multiple databases.

Comment: @GluePear would you mind removing the Accepted tag from my answer? It doesn't answer your question and I'd like to remove it. Stack doesn't allow removing Accepted answers.

Answer (score 8):

I understand that you want to create two databases in the same container, right? I think it goes against microservices architecture principles.

Anyway, I think this is possible when you are initializing a fresh instance:

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical order.

Update the file under mariadb/mysql directory [link](https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/issues/15) :

```
DROP USER IF EXISTS 'MYSQL_USER';
CREATE USER 'MYSQL_USER'@'%';
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS MYSQL_DATABASE;
GRANT ALL ON MYSQL_DATABASE.* TO 'MYSQL_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'MYSQL_PASSWORD';
 --------------your new NewDB----------------------
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS NewDB;
GRANT ALL ON NewDB.* TO 'MYSQL_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'MYSQL_PASSWORD';
```